# TensorFlow lib in anaconda3 Jupiter can't see my GPU NVIDIA GeForce MX 150

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

`TensorFlow` lib in `anaconda3` `Jupiter` can't see my `GPU NVIDIA GeForce MX 150`. When I use `tf.test.gpu_device_name()` I get `''`

When I use `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()`
I get `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')] but Pytorch can see it`

Comment: Please match the version of cuda and tensorfow if you have mistakenly installed incompatible versions. I also had similar kind of issue while installing, had to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: This is generally due to incompatible between `Tensorflow`, `CUDA` and `cuDNN`. You can refer compatible details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). The `tf.test.gpu_device_name()` function deprecated and it will be removed in a future version. Instead use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`.Thanks!